# How to pass arguements to apply_filters?

Tags: wordpress

Here is the scenario:

```
 if( apply_filters( 'example_filter', false, $type ) ) {
        // do something
 }
```

I want to make `$type` available within `// do something` block or pass from the `callback_function`.

```
$type = 'select';
function callback_function( $bool, $type ) {
    return true;  
}
add_filter( 'example_filter', 'callback_function', 10, 2 );
```

How can I pass the arguement from the `callback_function` inside `apply_filters` scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot pass additional variables back from the `apply_filters` function in WordPress (reference or not), however, there are a couple workarounds. If your code is designed to handle it, your second parameter (the one after the filter name that gets returned from the `apply_filters` call) could be changed to a non-boolean value or as a global variable (not recommended):

```
$type = 'select';
if( false !== ($type = apply_filters( 'example_filter', false, $type ))  ) {
    // Returned $type available here (if it is not boolean false)
}
```

Definition:

```
function callback_function( $type ) {

    if( /* is valid conditional */ ) {
        return $type; // Default value
    } else if ( /* another valid condition */ ) {
        return 'radio';
    }

    // else not valid
    return false;  
}
add_filter( 'example_filter', 'callback_function', 10 );
```

---

---

Another way is to use global variables (not recommended):

```
$GLOBALS['type'] = 'select';
if( apply_filters( 'example_filter', false ) ) {
    // $GLOBALS['type'] available here
}
```

Definition:

```
function callback_function( $bool ) {
    global $type;
    $type = 'radio';
    return true;  
}
add_filter( 'example_filter', 'callback_function', 10 );
```

---

Reference: https://www.geeklab.info/2010/04/wordpress-pass-variables-by-reference-with-apply_filter/